# Xamarin.Forms Azure.Devops build failing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-devops

I have an older Xamarin.Forms app which I've upgraded to 3.1.0. It all builds fine for me locally but when I want to build it on Azure devops it fails. It shows the following error for each xaml file. We have the netstandard lib added via NuGet:

```
<package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
```

This is the error I get:

```
App.xaml : error : Failed to resolve assembly: 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51']
```

Any suggestion how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent or private agent?

Comment: I'm using hosted agent. "Pool: Hosted macOS Agent: Hosted Agent"